# Cordova 4.0 Linear-Gradient color CSS3 not working on android devices

Tags: android, css, cordova

I'm building a Cordova app and I'm using linear gradient with a div, it have been shown in all browsers but when I build the app and open it using my android device I have no gradient effect shown. 
this is the code which I tried:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f1f0f0 0%, #ffffff 100%)!important;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f1f0f0), color-stop(100%,#ffffff))!important;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f1f0f0 0%,#ffffff 100%)!important;
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f1f0f0 0%,#ffffff 100%)!important;
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f1f0f0 0%,#ffffff 100%)!important;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f1f0f0 0%,#ffffff 100%)!important;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f1f0f0', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 )!important;
```

and I have also tried this code:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#f1f0f0),color-stop(50%,#FCFCFC), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,  top, bottom, from( #ffffff), to( #f1f0f0)) !important; 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f1f0f0, #FCFCFC, #ffffff) !important; 
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(#f1f0f0, #FCFCFC, #ffffff) !important; 
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(#f1f0f0, #FCFCFC, #ffffff) !important; 
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(#f1f0f0, #FCFCFC, #ffffff) !important; 
background-image:         linear-gradient(#f1f0f0, #FCFCFC, #ffffff) !important;
```

but it does not make any change ..
any idea or solution ?

Comment: I used this to set a background gradient:  `code`background: linear-gradient(RGB(70,107,176),RGB(255,255,255));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(RGB(70,107,176),RGB(255,255,255)); `code`  Reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/images/gradients_mobile.html

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using Crosswalk instead on the default webview that Cordova uses by default. When you install Crosswalk this is going to replace the buggy webview that Android comes with and uses Crosswalk browser instead.

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html